URDF Exporter Add-On Not Working in Fusion 360
I'm trying to transfer my custom-made manipulator to a URDF file, but I'm encountering issues with the URDF Exporter add-on in Fusion 360. When I select the add-on and click the run button, the file explorer window for saving the URDF file doesn’t appear.
Initially, I thought the issue was with my model, so I followed a different tutorial and created a new model according to its instructions. However, I found that this model also didn’t run properly with the add-on.
Could this issue be caused by importing other STL files and using them together with the model? I have some fixed joints in the model, but even when I only used revolute joints, the add-on still didn’t work. I made sure to save everything, and I defined all names in English.
Has anyone else experienced similar issues, or could there be another reason the add-on isn't functioning as expected?
I used URDF_Exporter_Ros2 from this source: https://github.com/dheena2k2/fusion2urdf-ros2/tree/master/URDF_Exporter_Ros2.


Although i have not tested this yet, there is a new tool/website that let you convert 3D Models (can be imported from Fusion as well as an STL) to URDF.
Maybe its worth giving it a try.
https://lever-robotics.github.io/URDF_creator/

Yes it was not working for me as weel, then I tried another another addon to convert to urdf 'ACDC4ROBOT' successfully able to convert the visuals, but some issues with joints.
